# I can't include other html files and it does not show the header

Tags: html

```
<html>
    <?require('header.html');?>
    <!-- page content -->
    <p>Welcome to the home of TLA Consulting.
        Please take some time to get to know us.</p>

    <p>We specialize in serving your business needs
        and hope to hear from you soon.</p>
    <?php
        require('footer.html');
    ?>
</html>
```

This is my code and it can't show the header when i open it in browser.
i had found many ways online still cant solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

youre missing `<?php`. it should be like this :

```
<?php require('header.html');?>
```

and make sure your page extention is `.php`

Comment: even i change to <?php require('header.php');?>

Comment: can you see the footer.html in your page?

Comment: whats your file extenstion ? if its html, change it to php like this : `index.php` and then try this : <?php include('header.html'); ?>

Comment: i changed all my file extension to php yet the result still the same

Comment: this is wiered :/ , dont change the header and footer extension , just your main file

Comment: the result still the same

Answer (score 0):

if your use `heade.html` and `footer.html` file include in `.html` file so its not work

because `html` page doesn't support `php` code so save your page in `.html` to `.php` and run again

and also change

`<?require('header.html');?>` to  `<?php require('header.html'); ?>`